# Magento 2: Get product sku by product attribute values

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

I have custom product attributes color_type, color, and size. I want to get product SKU by using values of these attributes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code. You need to just filter product collection with the custom attribute option values.

For Example color Attribute - Red option has value 999 in DB.

A] For single color value Filter.

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('eq' =>  $colorValue));
```

B] For Multiple color values Filter.(EX : 998,999 comma-separated by explode function)

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('color', array('in' => explode(',', $colorValues)));
```

C] Full code with example.

```
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,

    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;

    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('color',  array('eq' => $colorValue));//Filter collection by color attribute option value
//echo $collection->getSelect(); // Print query for verification
    


foreach ($collection as $product) {
        //echo '<pre>', print_r($product->getdata()); //For full product details.
    echo $product->getSku(); //print product sku.    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: It is working. Thanks.